# Display thumbnails in C#

Tags: c#, image, thumbnails

I am working on an album viewer using C#. As part of the application, I need to have all the images of the selected folder to be displayed as thumbnails. I dont know how to create the thumbnails.

Any code or links or suggestions to accomplish the functionality would be really helpful. Thank You.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Getting a list of files for a folder, reading an image from file, creating a thumbnail version of that image, displaying that thumbnail, something else?

Comment: @hans : creating a thumbnail version of the image

Answer (score 3):

```
public System.Drawing.Image GetThumbnailImage(int thumbWidth, int thumbHeight, System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort callback, System.IntPtr callbackData)
    Member of System.Drawing.Image

Summary:
Returns a thumbnail for this System.Drawing.Image.

Parameters:
thumbWidth: The width, in pixels, of the requested thumbnail image.
thumbHeight: The height, in pixels, of the requested thumbnail image.
callback: A System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort delegate. In GDI+ version 1.0, the delegate is not used. Even so, you must create a delegate and pass a reference to that delegate in this parameter.
callbackData: Must be System.IntPtr.Zero.

Returns:
An System.Drawing.Image that represents the thumbnail.
```

Answer (score 1):

check [this article](http://www.csharp-station.com/articles/thumbnails.aspx). It may will help you... The code creates an Image object from the image supplied in the textbox. Using the Image.GetThumbnailImage(), the code then creates a thumbnail image with a size of 100*100.

Comment: can you tell what the zip contains so people do not have to download it blindly ?

Comment: I've changed the link to be to the actual article that contains the zip file. That seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Yoko: No problem. A blind link to a zip file just seems like it'll make some people upset. This way they can check out the article and then grab the zip file containing the full source code if they are interested.

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult DisplayGalleryThumbs(string galleryId)
    {
        int pageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(galleryId.Split('_')[2]);
        Guid feedId = new Guid(galleryId.Split('_')[1]);
        var images = _feedDomain.ShowPostById(feedId.ToString()).Images;

        int totalNumberOfPages = CountNumberOfPages(images);

        string action = galleryId.Split('_')[3];

        var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<FeedImage>>();
        var pagedImages = new List<FeedImage>();
        int i = 1;
        int a = 1;
        foreach (FeedImage image in images)
        {
            pagedImages.Add(image);
            if (i % NumberOfImagesPerPage == 0)
            {
                dict.Add(a, pagedImages);
                a++;
                pagedImages=new List<FeedImage>();
            }
            if (i >= images.Count()) dict.Add(a, pagedImages);
            i++;
        }
        if (action=="next")
        {
            pageNumber += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            pageNumber -= 1;
        }


        var galleryModel = new FeedThumbGalleryModel
                               {
                                   Images = dict.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Key == pageNumber).Value,
                                   FeedId = feedId,
                                   PageNumber = pageNumber,
                                   NumberOfPages = totalNumberOfPages,
                                   NumberOfImagesPerPage = NumberOfImagesPerPage,
                                   TotalNumberOfImages = images.Count()
                               };

        return PartialView("~/Views/Feed/_DisplayGalleryThumbs.cshtml", galleryModel);
    }




@helper Render(FeedThumbGalleryModel model)
```

{

```
if (model.Images != null)
{

    string linkNext = "linkNext_" + model.FeedId + "_" + model.PageNumber + "_next";
    string linkPrev = "linkPrev_" + model.FeedId + "_" + model.PageNumber + "_prev";

    string thumbFeedId = "feedThumbDiv_" + model.FeedId;
    <div id="@thumbFeedId">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 30px;vertical-align: top;">
                    @if (model.NumberOfPages > 1)
                    {
                        if (model.PageNumber <= model.NumberOfPages && model.PageNumber > 1 || model.PageNumber == model.NumberOfPages)
                        {
                            <a class="page-action" href="#" id="@linkPrev">Prev</a>
                        }  
                    }
                </td>
                <td style="width: 120px;vertical-align: top">
                    @if (model.NumberOfPages>1)
                    {
                         for (int a = 1; a <= model.NumberOfPages; a++)
                         {
                             int currentPage = a - 1;
                             string pageLink = "linkNext_" + model.FeedId + "_" + currentPage + "_next";
                             string classname = a==model.PageNumber ? "page-number-list" : "page-number-list1";

                             <a href="#" id="@pageLink" class="@classname">@a</a>
                        }
                    }

                </td>
                <td style="width: 220px;vertical-align: top;">
                        @if (model.PageNumber < model.NumberOfPages)
                        {
                            <a class="page-action" href="#" id="@linkNext">Next</a>
                        }
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px;vertical-align: top;">
                    @{var thisId = "SeeAll_" + model.FeedId;}
                    @if (model.TotalNumberOfImages > 12)
                    {
                        <a id="@thisId" class="view-all">View All</a>
                    }

                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top">
                    <div class="number-of-images">
                       @model.TotalNumberOfImages images  
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <div style="width: 660px;padding-top: 10px">
                        @{int i = 1;}
                        @foreach (FeedImage m in model.Images)
                        {
                            string thumbThumb = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DisplayThumbPath"] + m.ImageId;
                            string imageUrl = "/feed/DisplayImage/" + model.FeedId + "_" + m.ImageId;

                            <div class="thumbnail image">
                                <a class='show-image' href="@imageUrl">
                                    <img border="0" class="image"  src="@thumbThumb" width="125" height="125" alt="" />
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            if (i % model.NumberOfImagesPerPage == 0)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>


    </div>

}
```

}

```
public class FeedImage
{

    public Guid ImageId { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public double ImageSize { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    public string ImageType { get; set; }
    public FeedPost Post { get; set; }
    public List<FeedLike> Likes { get; set; }
    public List<FeedComment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string DateCreatedIso8601 { get; set; }
}

private int CountNumberOfPages(List<FeedImage> images)
    {
        if (images == null) return 0;

        return (images.Count() + NumberOfImagesPerPage - 1) / NumberOfImagesPerPage;
    }

$("[class='page-action']").live('click', function () {
    var feedArr = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    var thisDivId = '#feedThumbDiv_' + feedArr[1];

    $.post('/Feed/DisplayGalleryThumbs', { galleryId: $(this).attr('id') },
            function (html) {
                $(thisDivId).replaceWith(html);
            });
    return false;
});
```

This is an ajax solution for thumbnail paging preview using MVC3.  Im using this for my news feed to list through image gallery.  Dont mind heavy use of tables in the view, my UI is a bit limited.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you a way I used in the past: Use a ListView and dynamically load the images in the associated ImageList. You can load the image in a thumbnailized form by using the strategy proposed by rdkleine. The important principle you have to follow is *don't load all images* if the user can't really see them. Using a listview you achieve this by setting `VirtualMode = true` and feed the image only when it is actually displayed.